# What is this blue callout in Prison Architect and how do I disable it?

Tags: prison-architect

I just loaded up my Prison Architect save and there's a strange icon by the arriving helicopter, that I can't figure out what it is trying to indicate. There have been some updates to Prison Architect since the last time I saved (December 2021), so could it possibly be related to that?

[image: Screenshot of Prison Architect]

The helicopter is configured to allow imports and exports of goods, no prisoner intake, and no civilian in/out. I watched, and the icon appears to disappear after the workmen remove the last item from the inbound shipment.

It's using the same callout mechanism that's used to alert you to things that actually *do* need your attention: your guard being attacked, a tunnel is found. But this seems to be a benign indicator of "you have an inbound shipment" and it shows up with every single helicopter, drawing attention regardless of where you're looking.

Is that what this blue callout is actually indicating (inbound helicopter shipment), or is it trying to communicate something else? And can I disable it, or somehow configure it to not be constantly trying to pull my attention to my helicopter port?

(And is there a proper name for this indicator? "Blue callout" doesn't seem to be what it's called so I wasn't lucky in Googling for more information.)

---

A later helicopter appears to take the callout with it as it flies away. This helicopter in the following screenshot is flying away; it contains a bunch of exports (12 logs, 16 wood). I reviewed my staff and there's no workman on board. So what is this callout, and why is it being shown to me?

[image: Another screenshot]

---

In the game options menu (Options → Game), there's a new option called "HUD Waypoints" which I thought might be related, but changing that from the default ("All On") to "Most Important" doesn't seem to hide this callout.

Comment: I think it _may_ indicate that the helicopter needs to be unloaded by workers, but then I don't understand why a helicopter that is _leaving_ also has the icon (maybe its bugged).  I tried finding a video to observe how this works since I don't have the game, but none of them showed this icon on their helicopters.

Comment: @TimmyJim  As much research as I did I found nothing either. It is a supply helicopter though so you are probably right about it needing to be unloaded.